# O que é 'coerência de leitura' em banco de dados?

Tags: banco-de-dados, oracle

Estou fazendo um artigo sobre o SGBD Oracle. E quando a versão 4 foi lançada, foi o primeiro Banco de Dados a ter **coerência de leitura**. Porém, eu não consigo achar o que é isso ou qual o significado desta funcionalidade para o contexto da época, ou até de hoje.

Comment: Dê o contexto..

Comment: Bom! Não tenho muito contexto, pois estou dando banco de dados I na faculdade, então não consigo imaginar um cenário. A unica coisa que tenho é [este artigo do Devmedia](https://www.devmedia.com.br/historia-da-oracle/4685).
Obs1: ano de 1984;
Obs2: Mineiro, você já tirou uma dúvida minha sobre uma calculadora que fiz em C#, vc disse na época que meu código era horrendo. kkkkkk... hoje eu entendo isso. Obrigado!

Comment: O termo em inglês é _read consistency_, e pelo que diz [aqui](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/consist.htm#CNCPT020)  existem diferentes níveis de consistência.